# How to use Vim to quickly see Mercurial or Git changes

Tags: git, vim, mercurial

As I'm editing a file in Vim, I would like to quickly highlight any changes I have made since my last commit, while still being able to edit the file.  Is there anything that comes close to doing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edit 2020-01-23: Searched quickly and FYI saw that there's another plugin that seems more VCS agnostic: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify

---

There's a new plugin that does this: [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter). It puts the changes in the Vim gutter whenever you save the file. Here's what it looks like in action:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I would accept this if the question was on Git only. Just what I want.

Comment: Have only been using it for a little while and it has been very useful. It makes seeing which portions of the file have changed very easy. A nice project might be to port it to include hg changes.

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at Tim Pope's [fugitive.vim](http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin.

I'm a git purist and usually drop into the command line for git, but when I'm in vim I find that this does most of what I need to do and yet I can still call git commands directly.

Comment: I like fugitive better than the vcscommand plugin, but I need hg support to, so I accepted the other answer.  Thanks for turning me on to fugitive, though!

Comment: Glad I like it. I wasn't sure till a friend suggested I try it myself, and now I find it does what I need.

Comment: @Abizern, sorry I realize this is an old question, but how do you use fugitive to highlight changed lines like the OP's question?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Sorry - I've moved on to Emacs and Magit since I wrote this answer. My Fugitive knowledge has fallen away.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon You have probably figured this out, but :Gdiff shows the differences. See the answer about gitgutter for another useful tool.

Answer (score 13):

Try [vcscommand](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90) plugin, use `:VCSVimDiff` to view differencies with current revision (supports both hg and git, probably some other SCM systems as well) and internal `:bdelete` (`:bd`) (on opened buffer of course, not on already existing) to stop diffing. If you are using gentoo, it is available in the repository: `app-vim/vcscommand`.

Comment: Accepting this one because it works on git and hg (and others too).  I like Tim Pope's fugitive better for git, however.

Answer (score 6):

one method is to do the following:

`:!git diff`

This will show the changes (to all files) in comparison to `HEAD`

to do a single file
`:!git diff path/to/file`

this is a quick way of doing it without switching different apps nor installing any plugins (which isn't always easy to do on some systems that you don't have control over).

it wont give you 'inline' highlighting but should work ok.

another way to do it quickly is to do a `:r !git diff` take a look at the changes then type `u` to undo the addition. This works nicely too, esp if you want to yank some text from `HEAD`

Comment: For the current file just do `:!git diff %` or `:!hg diff %`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a site on using git and vim together:

http://www.osnews.com/story/21556/Using_Git_with_Vim

I use the git.vim one, and every time I need a diff I can check it with `\gd`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this (no plugins required):

```
:new | r ! hg annotate -un #
```

This run `hg annotate` on the filename of the current buffer, then dumps the output in a new buffer.

This form of command is obviously not specific to git and hg.  You can capture the results of any shell command this way.

Answer (score 2):

This works for both Hg and Git:
https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify

Answer (score 2):

For Mercurial, an equivalent of `fugitive` is `lawrencium`: http://bolt80.com/lawrencium

It supports both side-by-side diff and a highlighted `diff`-like view (basically what you get from `hg diff <file>`.

(disclaimer: I'm the author)