# Vim: highlight changes compared to latest repo commit

Tags: git, vim, mercurial

If I am editing a file in a Git/Hg repo, is there any plugin that helps highlighting newly added/changed/deleted lines in Vim? Please note that I am not looking for a side by side comparison thing. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Vim to quickly see Mercurial or Git changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412039/how-to-use-vim-to-quickly-see-mercurial-or-git-changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the vim-signify plugin, there exists a whole bunch of other plugins that does the same:

[changesPlugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3052)

[sign-diff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2712)

[quickfixsigns](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2584)

[svndiff](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1881)

[git-gutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter)

(not all of them work with all vcs though).

Comment: vim signify works perfectly for me, but thanks for the list anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin can display the changes in the gutter, not side by side comparison:

https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify

Answer (score 0):

you could just issue a ! command and do git status there...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the fugitive plugin found [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975)

It only works for git repositories but has a side by side `Gdiff` command.  It also has a `Glog` command that will find recent commits for a file.

Answer (score 0):

For Mercurial, an equivalent of `fugitive` is `lawrencium`: http://bolt80.com/lawrencium

It supports both side-by-side diff and a highlighted `diff`-like view (basically what you get from `hg diff <file>`.

(disclaimer: I'm the author)